# Validating 2 form array inputs, so that their sum is equal to 100%

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page where I am building a table of values for editing, and then also incorporating new rows, which I have encapsulated into a single form.

Both the existing table rows (`percent_owned[]`) and the new rows (`new_percentage_ownership[]`) added together should equal 100, or the validation should fail and the user should amend the form.

Code for existing rows are:

```
foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $id2 = $row['id'];
    $owner_name = $row['owner_name'];
    $owner_id = $row['owner_id'];
    $percent_owned = $row['percent_owned'];

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td style="text-align:center"><small><input style="border:none; text-align:center" name="id2[]" type="text"  placeholder="id2" value="';
        echo $id2;
        echo '" readonly></small></td>';

        echo '<td style="text-align:center"><small><input style="border:none; text-align:center" name="owner_id[]" type="text"  placeholder="owner_id" value="';
        echo $owner_id;
        echo '" readonly></small></td>';

        echo '<td style="text-align:center"><small><input style="border:none; text-align:center" name="owner_name[]" type="text"  placeholder="owner_name" value="';
        echo $owner_name;
        echo '" readonly></small></td>';

        echo '<td style="text-align:center"><small>';
        ?>
        <input name="percent_owned[]" id="percent_owned" type="number" class="numeric" style="text-align:center" placeholder="percent_owned" value="<?php echo $percent_owned; ?>">
        <?php 
        echo '</small></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
Database::disconnect();
```

Code for new table rows (generated through a javascript function) is:

```
<td>
    <label for="new_owner_id">Owner ID&nbsp;</label>
    <select id="new_owner_id" name="new_owner_id[]">
        <?php if (!isset($new_owner_id)) { 
            echo '<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Owner</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="';
            echo $new_owner_id;
            echo '" selected>';
            echo $new_owner_id;
            echo '</option>';
        } ?>


        <option value="0">Unallocated / Available</option>
        <?php
        $new_owner_id_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, owner_name FROM owner ORDER BY owner_name ASC");
        while ($rows = $new_owner_id_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $new_owner_id_value = $rows['id'];
            ?>
            <option value="<?= $new_owner_id_value?>"><? echo $rows['owner_name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
</td>

<td>
    <label for="new_percentage_ownership">% Ownership&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="number" class="numeric"  id="new_percent_owned" name="new_percentage_ownership[]" value="0" required>
</td>
```

Question:

Both the array inputs `percent_owned[]` and `new_percentage_ownership[]` I want to be able to total 100, otherwise return false and enable me to edit the form again. my code results the form submitting anyway despite having the validation javascript element in place (not sure if it is correct though) but I thought at least something might happen.

the form is set to:
`<form class="form-horizontal" id="ownership_update_form" action="horse_ownership_update.php?id=<?php echo $sid ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="validate_ownership_form()">`

the javascript function I have set up to validate my inputs is:

```
<script>
function validate_ownership_form() {
    var val1 = document.forms["ownership_update_form"]["percent_owned[]"].value;
    for ( var i = 0; i < document.forms["ownership_update_form"]["percent_owned[]"].length; i++ ){
        count = count + val1[i];
        if ( count != 100 ) {
            alert("Please ensure 100%");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

So my question is - how do I take two `<input type="number" name="name[]">` inputs and total the arrays to see if they sum to 100?

Thankyou in advance for any comments/pointers you may have.

PS I also know that I am mixing PDO and MySQLi in here, that's being fixed :0)

---

Answer - working code:

```
<script>
    function validate_ownership_form() {
        var count = 0;
        var val1 = document.forms["ownership_update_form"]["percent_owned[]"];
        for ( var i = 0; i < val1.length; i++ ){
            count = count + Number(val1[i].value);
        }
        if ( count != 100 ) {
            alert("Please ensure 100%, currently percentage is: " +count+"%");
            event.preventDefault();
        } 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Your `return false` from inside the function doesn’t get noticed by anyone outside. With this kind of old-school event handling added via HTML attributes, you need to pass the return value on to the next “level”, `onsubmit="return validate_ownership_form()"`. Only this way the form submission will actually be prevented (if your function indeed returned false.)

Comment: @04FS Thankyou - that's got the alert coming up, however when I added the count variable to the alert like ```alert("Please ensure 100%, currently percentage is: " +count); ```, count presents as NaN, which means there must be an error in the way my function is calculating the sum of the array. any pointers gratefully received!

Comment: You are trying to add to a variable that by the looks of it wasn’t even initialized properly at that point - so add that.

Comment: @04FS thank you for the pointer - I also got rid of ```return false;``` my code (now working!) looks like this:```<script>
    function validate_ownership_form() {
     var count = 0;
  var val1 = document.forms["ownership_update_form"]["percent_owned[]"];
        for ( var i = 0; i < val1.length; i++ ){
            count = count + Number(val1[i].value);
        }
        if ( count != 100 ) {
            alert("Please ensure 100%, currently percentage is: " +count+"%");
            event.preventDefault();
        } 
    } 
</script>```

Comment: Nah, with that type of old-school event handling you should rather keep the version that is using `return false` - here you would be relying on the global event object, which is not recommended, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event (According to the compatibility table, this should not even work in Firefox, unless it is started with a specific flag …)